# How to go back to the previous fragment properly?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to handle the back button in a fragment. I want it to go back to the fragment it came from, but the `@Override` I've doesn't override from its superclass, but I don't why. Futhermore the method `onBackPressed()` is never used. I think it's weird as it works in my activities.

```
public class RateFrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private RatingBar ratingBar;
private Button rateknap;
private Forslag forslag;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater i, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rod = i.inflate(R.layout.activity_rate, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    forslag = ((AnnonceDisplay) this.getActivity()).getForslag();
    getActivity().setTitle(forslag.getTitle());

    ratingBar = (RatingBar) rod.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    rateknap = (Button) rod.findViewById(R.id.rateknap);
    rateknap.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rod;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == rateknap) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage("Vil du give " + ratingBar.getRating() + " stjerner?")
                .setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                launchintent();
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Nej", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        }
                ).show();


    }
}

private void launchintent() {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment f = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        fm.popBackStack();
    } else{
        getActivity().finish();
    }
       }
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.Forside) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), Forside.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.Logud){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), LogInd.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return true;
}
@Override //Method does not override method from its superclass
public void onBackPressed() { //Method onBackPressed is never used
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        getActivity().finish();
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    return;
 }
}
```

Before anyone says it's a possible duplicate, I've searched here on Stackoverflow and Google. I actually got this `Override` from here, so please tell me what is wrong, and how I fix it.

Thanks :)

Comment: dont handle back pressed in the fragment, do it in the activity. So you override the activities onBackPressed and finsh or pop the back stack there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the onBackPress on your Activity like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

}
```

Comment: Now I don't have an error with the override but `Cannot resolve method onBackPressed`

Comment: Don't you mean in my fragment?

Comment: I've edited it in my fragment but it can still not resolve the method onBackPressed

Comment: Do I've to delete the things I did in the fragment before?

Comment: what do you mean? Only the OnBackPressed method whick is useless

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Just a question, was my question good enough? it's the first time I ask from this account, so I hope it's good :)

Comment: yes it was good because it's a tricky part the back press on fragments :)